# $X$ is a random variable. Let $ g(X)$ be a function of $X$. Is $p(X=a)=p(g(X=a))$? Please explain

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm not getting concepts related to this. Shouldn't $p(g(X=a))=p(X=a)?$ where $a \in $ the set of all values of $X$.

Edit:I'm pretty sure the problem is that I don't get the notation but online sources aren't helping

Comment: $g(X=a)$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p(x=2)=0.2$ and $p(x=4)=0.5$. Let $g(x)=x^2$.

Then $p(x=2)=0.2\neq 0.5=p(x=4)=p(g(x=2))$

Comment: This is funny, I understand neither the question nor the accepted and upvoted answer (and in fact I must admit I suspect neither makes any sense).

Comment: @Did- And I suspect you're right. Could you shed some more light on Thomas Andrews's comment, regarding the fact that $p(g(x=a))$ does not make sense?

Comment: What do YOU think g(X=a) might mean? (This question was already asked to the OP, I wonder why they stay silent.)

Comment: The way I interpreted $p(g(x=a))$ was $p(g(a))$. 

$g(a)$ is just a point on the x-axis.

Comment: If p(X=a) is meaningful, then p is a probability measure, defined on events, hence p(b) for b real, for example b=g(a), is meaningless. If p(g(a)) exists, then p(X=a) does not. (Anyhow, g(X=a) does not exist because g is a function from R to R and [X=a] is an event.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether I have fully understood your question. I assume that $p$ are probability densities. Densities are not invariant under a change of variables. The probability within a volume element, however, is invariant under a change of variables. In mathematics, 
$$
p(x) \ne p(y(x)),
$$
but
$$
p(x)\text{d}x = p(y(x))\text{d}y.
$$

In fact, we see that the probability densities are related by a *Jacobian*,
$$
p(x) = p(y(x)) \frac{\text{d}y}{\text{d}x}.
$$